# Como puedo cambiar la imágen de un sprite renderer por código?

Tags: c#, unity2d

```
{
    public GameObject destroy;

    private Animator animator;
   
    public SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }


    //space

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Destroy(destroy);

            animator.SetBool("button", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            (cambio de sprite)
 
        }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Destroy(destroy);

            animator.SetBool("button", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            (cambio de sprite)
        }
    }
}
```

Intento que cuando estés dentro del trigger del objeto, solo si presionas la tecla espacio se cambie a otra imágen.

Comment: No vandalices tu pregunta. Es una actitud inmadura con la que solo te ganarás votos negativos y reportes, terminando por ser cerrada.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Te sugiero que te informes bien de Unity. Viendo un buen tutorial/curso. Para recibir entrada del jugador te conviene hacerlo en una función que se ejecute frecuentemente. Se suele utilizar `Update` pero podrías hacerlo dentro de [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html). Y sobre cambiar el sprite: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html

Comment: perdonen por vandalizarla no sabia como podria que mi pregunta se publique no pasara de nuevo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pasa 1 Sprite a tu componente por referencia

```
[Serializefield]
Sprite imagen1;
//Arrastras la imagen desde el editor
```

o

```
public Sprite imagen1;
//Arrastras la imagen desde el editor
```

SpriteRenderer tiene internamente un atributo, sprite, que es del tipo Sprite.

Le asignas

```
 if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {      
            sprite.sprite = imagen1;
        }
```

Tambien te recomiendo cambiar tu variable sprite por algo como miSpriteRender.